# post to specific people in google+ and retrieve these posts from google plus in android

Tags: android, google-plus, android-maps-v2

I am creating an android app, i would like to know how to post to specific people in google plus. 
I would also like to know how to parse google + posts? Especially the ones that is shared only to you. Is there any way of reading these posts and getting the data? I would also like to delete this post from google + after i get the data. Is it possible?
The app is basically used to post a particular information such as co-ordinates etc. to google+ and then retrieve the data from the other end and display their location in the map. 
I would also like to parse the post as soon as i get a notification on google+. can we do this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently watched a presentation from the Google I/O about Google+ Sign-In. It may could be a nice solution for your App to use Google+ features. The user can easily use it's stored account on the device. It's very comfy to use and also easy to implement. I recommend to take a look at the presentation. Here I have two useful links:

The First one ist the Google I/O talk, the second one refers to the Google Developers overview

- [Google I/O](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KBHf1EODuk&list=WL18261C4D9D540938) at [19:00](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_KBHf1EODuk&feature=player_detailpage&list=WL18261C4D9D540938#t=1135s) they start to talk about implementing interactive posts
- [Google Developers](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/plus.html)

Comment: As +Woda mentioned, you can target Interactive Posts to a specific user, which is probably what you should do.There is not a private data read API and there is not an API to remove an interactive post from a user's stream.

Comment: Thanks +Woda. Your posts were helpful. But google+ new update has released a new location service. Is there any chance of using them with the mPlusClient. If so how do I get the location servicces?